# Mongoose model unable to call its functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't get Mongoose to use its functions

```
var boxSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    identify: String,
    name: String,
    phone: String,
});

var Box = mongoose.model("Box", boxSchema);
Box.create({
    identify: "Foo",
    name: "",
    phone: "",
},(err,box)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(`box created! ${box}`);
    }
})
```

It seems a bit silly. Looks like everything is in place but the create method won't even trigger.
Everything is imported up top

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
```

My connection with the db is done like this:

```
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/depo';
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

I also have a gridfs storage and multer implementation but it doesn't seem to meddle with the app.
Any idea why it might not work? :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually found the problem. There is this conn object that I'm creating in order to use the GridFS can not be used as a mongodb connection aswell. So i had to add a mongoose.connect around there aswell.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/depo", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```